# Optimize Python Code to read various inputs as time limit exceeded

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, time-complexity

Below is my python code I want to be able to optimize my code for different inputs and pass the time limit error I keep getting for my current code. Some sample inputs are for 3 cases n there would be a line for each case space separated as so.

I've tried creating different ways of getting the inputs, even for large value of inputs as well but I can't pass the time limit error for different test cases. If someone could show me where on my code, it's slowing this process down that would be very helpful

```
 Sample tests:
 3
 3 2 1 1
 2 1 1 1
 5 2 1 1

n = int(input())
if 1<= n <= 100000:
counter = 0
while counter < n:
    i = 1
    a = list(map(int, input().split(' ')))
    D = a[0]
    d = a[1]
    P = a[2]
    Q = a[3]
    if (1 <= d <= D <= 1000000) and d <= D <= 100:
        if 1 <= P and Q <= 1000000:
            days = 1
            while i <= D:
                if i % d == 0:
                    if days == 1:
                        Production = P + Q
                        Total_money = d*P
                        days+=1
                    elif days > 1:
                        Total_money+= Production*d
                        days+= 1
                elif i%d == 1 and i == D:
                    if days <= 2:
                        Total_money+= Production
                    else:
                        Total_money+= Production + Q
                i+= 1
            counter+= 1
            print(Total_money)
```

Comment: How do you know the issue is the time reading the input vs. processing?  For instance, you have a while loop i.e. `while i <= D:` for each line of input.  What is the processing supposed to be doing--perhaps it could be done more efficiently.

Comment: To check if the problem is reading the input, then leave the input but remove the processing code and have it just output any value (such as 0).  If the system then reports you have the wrongs answers rather than the time limit exceeded then you know your processing is what's taking too long.

Comment: Hey @DarryIG,  D represents days. The initial rate of printing the currency is P dollars per day and they increase the production by Q dollars after every interval of d days. For example, after d days the rate is P+Q dollars per day, and after 2d days the rate is P+2Q dollars per day, and so on. Output the amount of money they will be able to print in the given period.

Comment: I actually believe it does have something to do with that while loop you mentioned, I think for larger test values it would take much longer.

Comment: @brian012--try solution I posted which calculates total money without looping.

Comment: @DarryIG, It works fine, thanks a lot! It looks like I needed to take the mathematical approach to really speed the process up and shorten the coding

Comment: @brian012--if you are solving coding competition problems (such as Hackerrank) then the solution requires an efficient algorithm rather than just working code.  Otherwise, you will run up against the time constraint on the tougher test cases.

Comment: @DarryIG I will keep that in mind, thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above code can be improved as follows.
Note: the conditionals are not necessary since they are normally provided to alert you to the range of values you have to contend with.

```
def calc_total_money(D, d, P, Q):
    '''

     Calculates the total money 

     The intervals are made up of:

    Days
    [   d days   |   d days   |  d days |  .... | d days | r days]

    Amounts per Day
    [P           |  P+Q       | P + 2*Q | P + 3*Q ...             ]

    '''
    intervals = D // d                    # Number of whole intervals  of d days
    r = D - d*intervals                   # Number of days in last interval (i.e. partial interval)

    if intervals == 0:
        # No whole intervals
        return P*r
    else:
        # intervals = number of intervals of d days (i.e. whole intervals)
        # Amount in whole intervals are:
        # P, P+Q, P + 2*Q, P + 3*Q, ... P + (intervals-1)*Q
        # This equals: P*intervals + Q*intervals*(intervals - 1)//2
        # Since each interval is d days we have amount from whole interval of:
        # amount_whole_intervals = (P*intervals + Q*intervals*(intervals - 1)//2)*d
        #
        # Amount per day in last partial interval:
        #  P + intervals*Q
        # There are r days in last partial interval, so amount in last partial interval is:
        # last_partial_amount = (P + intervals*Q)*r
        #
        # Total = amount_whole_intervals + last_partial_amount
        return  (P*intervals + Q*intervals*(intervals - 1)//2)*d + (P + intervals*Q)*r

    
for _ in range(int(input())):
    D, d, P, Q = map(int, input().split(' '))
    print(calc_total_money(D, d, P, Q))
```

**Tests**

Input

```
 3
 3 2 1 1
 2 1 1 1
 5 2 1 1
```

Output (same as OP code)

```
4
3
9
```